# What process is using UDP port?

Tags: macos, unix

I am trying to install a server that needs to use the port `3052` and it's not working. I have a feeling another process has that port. I see:

```
% netstat -anv | grep 3052
udp4       0      0  *.3052          *.*          196724   9216    335      0
```

So what does this mean? Does some process have UDP port `3052` taken, and how do I find out what it is?

Comment: PID 335. Try running `ps aux | grep 335`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `lsof` command to get more insight into what process is using a specific port. In your case, you'd issue the command `lsof -i4UDP:3052`. Read the `man` page for more information about how to use the tool, as it is slightly different between current and older macOS versions.

One of the columns displayed by `lsof`, the PID column, will show the ID of the process that is using that port. You could find out more about the process using `ps`.